# How to assign value to output array in verilog

Tags: verilog

So, I have a LED[7:0], and I had a loop that loops 7 times, so I try to do this assignment

```
for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
  LED[i] = (some logics)
```

and this just gives me error : object on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type"?

but if I program it this way:

```
LED[0] = ...
LED[1] = ...
   .
   .
   .
```

It works, I am using Quarts II Verilog , so , this has been bugging me for a whole day ... Thank you all so much

Comment: Please show real code. I think what you have there can work, but need to see your declarations of led and what is surrounding this for loop.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted. The wire/reg thing is completely illogical, and it's hardly surprising that it causes confusion.

Comment: @EML In my opinion, because the question isn't clear. It might be any typo, we have not enough code to make our minds and help out. At least I think that's the reason ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that logic you'd probably like to use *for generate* loop:

```
generate
   for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin : led_loop
      assign LED[i] = (some logic);
   end 
endgenerate
```

Comment: For loops inside an always block are synthesable if they can be statically unrolled, it looks like the error points to some thing on the right hand side.

Comment: @Morgan: I think LED is defined as wire, while it should be reg.

Comment: Sure, but all he has to do is declare it as a reg. A generate is overkill for this. Oh - and fix the i++ to i=i+1, assuming that this actually is Verilog.

Comment: @EML: there is no "i++" in my answer.

Comment: @Qiu EML was referring to the question. It would just need to change`wire`/`reg` declaration and fix the `i++` syntax. NB:`i++` is supported in SystemVerilog.